# Searching for book recommendations

Tags: mixing

First of all sorry, because this question will definately be quite dull.

When it comes to 'later stages' of audio post-production I generally have no idea of all these many terms and procedures. Internet searches just confuse me more and more, so I'm searching for a book which covers the topic structured.

Due to my inability, I will just throw in a few terms so you can conclude about which field I'm talking: upmixing/downmixing from different sources LCR/LtRt/5.1/etc. ; nearly everything with 'Dolby' in its name (encoders, decoders, processors, codecs...); sound formats (AC3, DTS...); print masters; DCP, bitstream, PCM, ...it could go on forever.

Answer (score 1):

I think the stage of mixing you are looking for is called "Mastering" this is generally the last stage in the progression of mixing (and may be the keyword you are missing). As for the different formats each has there own specs and it will really depends on the application you are shooting for. Most music is mixed down in stereo as that is really what its consumed in for the most part. If you are talking about movie or video game audio you will see lots of 5.1 or 7.1 audio. LCR is common for live settings and some of the ideas carry over to the center channel when 5.1/7.1 mixing. If you pick a specific topic we may be able to point you towards a better book.

[Here is a list of books](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=audio%20mastering&tbm=bks) you may want to look at. I have not read any of them so I wont comment further than pointing you that way.

Edit --

As per movies getting "mastered" [see this link](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/mastering-forum/547416-do-film-soundtracks-get-mastered.html) for some discussion on it. It seems that it does and doesn't happen but it does seem some of the stuff carries over.

Comment: Would you not find books about music mastering rather than film mixing that way?

Comment: Many of the theories are cross compatible and can be applied to both tasks. While there are certain case specific things my background is mainly in music but ill see if I can find some good film books as well.

Comment: I also heard mastering exclusively in reference to music. But I'll see if some of those books provide useful information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Principles of Digital Audio by Ken Pohlmann seems to be widely accepted by the Music Technology community I've been exposed to. It covers all the topics you mentioned and more.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! Thanks. I will have a look at it.